# Typescript generics don't resolve concrete types as I would like them to be

Tags: typescript, generics, keyof

I have a class that keeps a list of item, but instead of keeping them in a flat array, it keeps them in an object map of which each property represents a *group of items*. Like if we'd have a list of cars and we'd group them per manufacturer.

```js
// object map
interface IObjectMap<TValue> {
    [key: string]: TValue;
}

// object map; same as interface but build using keys union type
type ItemMap<TMapKeys extends keyof IObjectMap<unknown>, TValue> = Record<TMapKeys, TValue[]>;

// just a function taking one parameter and returning a result
type GetterFunc<TInput, TResult> = (item: TInput) => TResult;

// object map where the value type of properties are getter functions returning a string
type GetterMap<TMapKeys extends keyof IObjectMap<unknown>, TInput> = Record<TMapKeys, GetterFunc<TInput, string>>;

class GroupedItems<
    TItem, // item type
    TGroupKeys extends keyof IObjectMap<unknown> // object map keys
> {
    public groups: ItemMap<TGroupKeys, TItem> = {} as ItemMap<TGroupKeys, TItem>;
    public countryGetters: GetterMap<TGroupKeys, TItem> = {} as GetterMap<TGroupKeys, TItem>;

    public addItems(items: TItem[], getGroupKey: GetterFunc<TItem, TGroupKeys>): void {
        this.items.concat(items);
        this.items
            .forEach(item => {
                let name = getGroupKey(item);
                if (this.groups[name] === undefined) {
                    // create placeholder for items
                    this.groups[name] = [];
                }
                // Put the item in the group
                this.groups[name].push(item);
            });
    }

    public assignGetters(getters: GetterMap<TGroupKeys, TItem>) {
        this.countryGetters= getters;
    }
}
```

There are two generic type parameters to the class:

- the type of items we'll be grouping (i.e. `Car`)
- the group keys (i.e. `'renault' | 'peugeot' | ...`)

The class members are then both defined as object maps:

- `groups` keep items in group arrays
- `countryGetters` is also an object map with the same properties as item groups, but they define a function that returns the manufacturer country of the car passed in

## Usage example

Above code seems to have no errors, but with its use it seems that types aren't getting resolved as they should. I would like the compiler/linter to complain when I would try to use an item group name, that isn't defined in a map or a union type of group keys...

```js
interface Car {
    model: string;
    year: number;
}

interface CarMakers<TValue> extends IObjectMap<TValue> {
    renault: TValue;
    peugeot: TValue;
}

let select = new GroupedItems<
    Car,
    keyof CarMakers<unknown>
>();

select.addItems([
        { model: 'R5', year: 1980, dummy: false }, // error; correct
        { model: '206', year: 2004 },
        { model: '3008', year: 2010 }
    ],
    car =>
        car.year < 2000
        ? 'audi' // should be an error; "audi" not in "keyof MakerGroups<>"
        : 'peugeot'
);
select.assignGetters({
    renault: () => 'France',
    audi: () => 'Germany' // should be an error; "audi" not in "keyof MakerGroups<>"
});
```

As you can see, group names aren't being resolved by the Typescript so my type definitions aren't being strict enough (I presume), hence I can invalidly manipulate non-existent groups. Upper code seems fine from the compile-time perspective, but should do the checks for me and intellisense should help me with filling up group names.

#### Here is the [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&target=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkBGArCCwCycADgDwAqAanADYCuEAfMgN4BQynyA2gNYQBPAFzIAzmCigA5gF0RVWgwDcbAL5s2YAcRSpIAWyJlyRgNKDRyCAA9IIACaX+AgPYw0WXPiOk6IXiAuAO4gjAA0yAr0TMgAvMgASnguUPYUZhYRUQzcMowqWjrIAOIQYJBQAGJ+CBSoIMR0YFlJonQ0YMzxABTABvL1jWAAlHHM5K3tYAXaKKXl0D4mJOYCljZ2jsjObh44eIQkvv6BIeGRg01dicmp6SuZJWUV1SC15JfNYhLSjPkaCBocFElmKUBcdB09j0EH0olIHC4HwMYURnHIYIhxFW61sEAcTkEuww+28Rz8AWCoTYzHYaOQjUwNGACGQUnBkNEIhhhiOGI52MeyNh1xYqmQwLQBiWmMhOKyPP+XAZdCZLOQCAh4CgAnmFS5TwWUBlAvlFwMovFkr1iz5ssFawVFpU9MZzNZcHs0IMol6PoGBlyESkZXtqxENqqNTqKMiYYsjGGIgAbi5gPZWPTlX1YaIs8quAA6GApACiiAAFn7YWNMwX6wWaGVkCA4PoUPEQ2B4wJq-phioG0PkMB3N0wBXgKJC+ysaJuK32zI4rF4n57BAYKAIPZRuxhwfkBOpzOBfPFxBl-FcoPD8r1Hflcfp7POQu25fC41RFWc-3bweqgDvS6iuqq7oSiCwBSCAka+l2+oRs8trGD2ohOiKe75pwz6FpqfgSLqyFQJYnbEaIAHIOooGgBU8BIMgADCcBQHWXD6C4G40CI4iSCAUiUQIEAsSIIB0PomDQCoNHgNA9EoMxxpwPwJEUNQ0TMBs+JbCSXiHMY6kMLS9JQPicBTPIhkQJROh0CGLhgJZijWWoGhNmAYgQE2+BxC2EBBCUAo7jy8L0opqLKjs7iKUQKnwhSpzUow3TAWwoheQchaet6ubdNw2GsMgHFcSIADkCQAKylREQkicgACMACcAAcAAMET2OJ+jCMg8A0OlVERAA9ENyAbqI0EgAAtGAwDtlYUDglASgaikpn4AVLBFZxXllQATK1ABs1XILVUAiAdrUACyDZt20lcgpUAMyta1zUnWdF2tfVrVUfSMgRVwCAsWMBXA1AhZncgpDIJdrUFQA-I95n2MApXICNYgVhCNAZpJEogAtS0rQARCjwAky2DkjoTJNRcgsXQPa8KMCTBVlbZ9lgKVbDAel3lgFlUEwXB3T7lwpmthZyApbWpWVFAcBvBA1X0uTIiy7EzClaUUD6ErAjo5jP443jKBK0TKSk+TlOBB5oDIHTRLuIzUDM6QrNqKlmogKILhNnhTYsSlKg+37Ac0C4UjdPzmWvsQojAWH-sQIWkfR7H+B4VqhFwcBQA) to tinker.

Comment: Your `IObjectMap` has a string index meaning that it should contain a value for ANY string.  `CarMakers` extends `IObjectMap` so `keyof CarMakers<unknown>` is every string, not just the specific keys of your object.

Comment: Turns out it's an easy fix :)  I'm typing up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the type of the `select` which you created it is `GroupedItems<Car, string | number>`.  So we can see that the problem is `TGroupKeys`.  We want it to be `'renault' | 'peugeot'` and instead we have `string | number`.

Your interface `IObjectMap` has an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures) meaning that it should contain a value for ANY string. `CarMakers` extends `IObjectMap` so `keyof CarMakers<unknown>` is every string (and numbers too), not just the specific keys of your object.  This is true for every object which extends `IObjectMap`.

Per the [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures),

> If you have a type with a string index signature, keyof T will be string | number (and not just string, since in JavaScript you can access an object property either by using strings (object["42"]) or numbers (object[42])).

We need to remove that index signature.  In fact, we can remove it everywhere.

Instead of extending `keyof IObjectMap<unknown>`, `TMapKeys` and `TGroupKeys` should extend either `string` or `PropertyKey` -- a built-in type which is the union of all valid property keys (`string | number | symbol`).

With those changes, we now get the desired errors:

```
Type '"audi"' is not assignable to type '"renault" | "peugeot"'
```

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'audi' does not exist in type 'Record<"renault" | "peugeot", GetterFunc<Car, string>>'
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/lm0lnm)